# Rewrite everything after a certain directory to that directories index.php (htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

Hi, so this may be asked elsewhere but I have searched and come up with irrelevant results.
I clearly don't know what to search for exactly.

I'm just trying to rewrite everything after a certain directory to that directories index.php.
Here is an example of the URL a visitor would SEE

`website.com/search/location/United%20States`

And I would like that URL to be rewritten server-side so that it loads `website.com/search/location/index.php`
(not a 301 redirect)

I would like the Url to stay the same but load the `index.php` script (to include United%20States so this can be passed to PHP to determine what the location is and if it is legitimate etc.).

Sorry I know that this will be somewhere already but I just can't find it
I have some code already but it is buggy and seems to choose when it wants to work and also sometimes uses `location/index.php/United%20States` which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your htaccess (which has to be in your root folder)

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^search/location/.+$ /search/location/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Apache web server, make sure you have mod-rewrite enabled and put .htaccess file into your WEBROOT/search/location directory. Put this into .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php [L]
```

This will internally redirect all requests, where file or directory does not exists, to index.php.

You could also put .htaccess file into your WEBROOT directory and write this into to:

```
RewriteRule ^search/location/.* /search/location/index.php
```

Hope this helps.